# Как обновить pip на винде 7 базовая (сервис пак 1)

Tags: pip

Собстна сабж:
не получается обновить pip

[image: Ругается: чтоб обновить pip - обновите pip]

Comment: Ну как бэ он намекает на более свежую версию (жёлтый текст). Стоит попробовать

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы обновить pip нужно использовать такую команду:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Для этого перейдите в папку как показано ниже на скриншоте:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

дальше переходим в эту папку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и прописываем путь:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот есть [туториал](https://datatofish.com/upgrade-pip/) по обновлению и подобный [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15221473/how-do-i-update-pip-itself-from-inside-my-virtual-environment).

P.S. Как уже было замечено в комментариях, вам было предложено обновиться в сообщениях системы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может я не совсем предельно ясно задал вопрос? Но дело в том, что: система предлагается обновить pip в ответ на процесс обновления pip-а....замкнутый круг...

Comment: какую команду вы используете? вы пробуете обновиться из директории пользователя, попробуйте перейти по пути который указан в моем ответе :)

Comment: всё верно я использую команду python -m pip install --upgade pip

Comment: короче, сделал все как рекомендуете -то же самое: пишет что не может обновить версию pip, для этого обновите версию  pip

Comment: все - разобрался, у меня же стоит версия 38 а не 37-32.